# I am trying to add HTML audio to my flask website but the audio bar is greyed out

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

When I independently open the same html file it works but when opened from flask it is greyed out. Does anyone have a solution to this?

[image]

[image]

I hope I can get a quick response. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your browser's console. There should be an error message.

For Chrome this would be

- right click on the content
- inspect
- "Console"